# Integral of self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T$ be a self-adjoint operator. Suppose there exists $c>0$ s.t., for every $x\in H$, $(Tx,x)\geq c(x,x)$
Then $S:=\int_{-\infty}^\infty (y^2+T^2)^{-1} \, dy$ is well-defined, and represent $S$ specifically.

I know that spectrum theorem $T=\int \lambda \, dE_\lambda$. But I can't prove well-defined of $S$ and represent.

Comment: If $H=\mathbb C$ and $T=c=1$ then the integral does not exist.

Comment: You are using $x$ with two different meanings.

Comment: In your example, $T$ is not self-adjoint.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't asked to look at $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(y^2+T^2)^{-1}dy$?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thanks. I have mistake. I edit.